# How to convert int to DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My plan is to make Day,  Month, Year, Hours, StartMinute a dropdown and the selected numbers of the dropdown is gonna be converted to a datetime and saved in the database

How to convert int to DateTime, right now i get a error in my StartTime. The error is "Sannot implictly convert type 'int' to 'System.DateTime'".

```
public class Job
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int StartHour { get; set; }
    public int StartMinute { get; set; }
    public int EndHour { get; set; }
    public int EndMinute { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartTime
    {
        get
        {
            return  Day + Month + Year + StartHour + StartMinute;
        }

        set
        {
            StartTime = Day + Month + Year + StartHour + StartMinute;
        }
    }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
```

Comment: Get your day year and ... and make string and than convert to dateTime

Comment: Instead of multiple controls add a single control of Calendar.

Comment: As an aside... what do you expect a setter of `StartTime` calling `StartTime = ...` to do?

Comment: Hmmm StartTime setter? - //EDIT Oops just @JonSkeet already alluded too, apologies.

Comment: Don't use parsing when you have the date segments as integer values, it's just a silly...

Comment: I want to save it in the database, The plan is to save a substitutes jobs, so you can see when the substitutes started and when he finnished

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is pritty simple if you have all the values as seperated Dropdowns:

```
int year = 2016, month = 2, day = 25, hour = 10, minute = 41;
DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0);
```

The last 0 in the "new [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)" is for the seconds-part

Edit for [`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/system.argumentoutofrangeexception) in the getter:

```
    public DateTime StartTime
    {
        get
        {
            if (Year < 1) Year = 1;
            if (Month < 1) Month = 1;
            if (Day < 1) Day = 1;
            if (StartHour < 0) StartHour = 0;
            if (StartMinute < 0) StartMinute = 0;
            return new DateTime(Day, Month, Year, StartHour, StartMinute, 0);
        }
        set
        {
            Day = value.Day;
            Month = value.Month;
            Year = value.Year;
            StartHour = value.Hour;
            StartMinute = value.Minute;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use one of the Constructors of [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You are just summing up some `int` and expecting the framework to recognize it as a `DateTime`. Your problem is, that the framework does not understand what you mean with the name `Year` and `Hour`.

Use the `DateTime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second)` constructor instead. In the way

```
StartTime = new DateTime(Year, Month, Day, StartHours, StartMinutes, 0)
```

Also I don't think to put this in a getter-function is not the right way because you are waiting for some user input. So you have to wait for an event to happen (changing one of the drop-downs or klicking on a button) before the variable `StartTime` can be set. Therefore, you probably have to set `StartTime` in a method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct conversion from number, or multiple numbers to structure (as [DateTime is a structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx)).

You have multiple [constructors for DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130.aspx). Number 6 ot of 12 says VS:

```
public DateTime( int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DateTime constructor:

> DateTime(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)
>   Initializes a new instance of the DateTime structure to the specified year, month, day, hour, minute, and second.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Job
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int StartHour { get; set; }
    public int StartMinute { get; set; }
    public int EndHour { get; set; }
    public int EndMinute { get; set; }

public DateTime StartTime
{
    get
    {
        return new DateTime(Year, Month, Day, StartHours, StartMinutes, 0);
    }
    set
    {
        Day = value.Day;
        Month = value.Month;
        Year = value.Year;
        StartHour = value.Hour;
        StartMinute= value.Minute;
    }
}
public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: `public DateTime(
 int year,
 int month,
 int day,
 int hour,
 int minute,
 int second
)`

year The year (1 through 9999).
month The month (1 through 12).
day The day (1 through the number of days in month).
hour
The hours (0 through 23).
minute
The minutes (0 through 59).
second
The seconds (0 through 59).

Comment: `public DateTime EndTime
{
    get
    {
        return new DateTime(Year, Month, Day, EndHour, EndMinute, 0);
    }
    set
    {
        Day = value.Day;
        Month = value.Month;
        Year = value.Year;
        EndHour = value.Hour;
        EndMinute= value.Minute;
    }
}`

Comment: also check initial values of your public properties. Initial value of int is 0. For some parameters of DateTime constructor 0 is out of range. initialize your properties in constructor.